# What is support and service method in java

Tags: java, oop

What is support and service method. What is the different between them and can you guys provide sample java code.

I did small research, according to my guess support method is set private or protected visibility to a method?. I'm not sure is it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're pretty arbitrary terms, not directly related to visibility. For example, a "support method" might be used throughout an application, but not really called a "service".

IMO a "service method" is something explicitly designed for use from outside of the application, exposed via a remote procedure call, URL, etc.

A "support method" is just that, something that's used as a utility, but I wouldn't necessarily restrict its visibility or make an assumption. For example, a client library might call service methods via RPC, but the application serving the requests, and client library, and the client application might make use of some of the same support ("utility") methods to perform useful domain- or application-specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of these terms as belonging to paradigms and as such having some relation to each other. Interpreting your statement, a *service* method might be the public API method provided, and a *support* method might be the internal method of an API implementation.

```
// API, not to be overriden, but service method for use:
public final void paint();

// One implementation, child of base class
@Override
protected void onPaint(Graphics2D g2, Context ctx) {
    ...

// Base class
protected void onPaint(Graphics2D g2, Context ctx) {
}
public void paint() {
    ...
    onPaint(g2, ctx);
}
```

This design pattern (service & requirement) allows to pass contextual information to the implementation and full control on usage and especially implementation.